# Extract from Reddit works fine but cannot save as excel file

Tags: r, reddit

I'm using `pushshiftr` to extract Reddit posts and works fine

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("whereofonecannotspeak/pushshiftr")
library(pushshiftr)
p<-ps_search_submissions(NA, subreddit = "disability", after = "2019-12-26", before = "2019-12-27")
```

from here:

https://github.com/dashstander/pushshiftr

In p now I have the posts but when I try to save into excel using this

write_xlsx(p, "C:/Users/Reddit/posts.xlsx")

I get the error:

```
Argument x must be a data frame or list of data frames
```

The argument in this case is a list, but couldn't find out how to export to excel

Comment: The output is a `nested` list and is not a data.frame

Comment: Yes, but how to convert this output to a data frame?

Comment: Well, the nested lists all have varying entrees (try `lapply(p, names)`). There seem to be 65 unique entrees, so you could just add the missing entrees to each sublist and then create a data frame with 65 columns and `length(p)` rows. The problem is that you'd need to give the new entrees a value, but there is no way of knowing what a good default value is (`NULL`? `NA`?). Furthermore, there may be more than 65 entrees possible if you change your function call (maybe you'll get 100 uniques if you extend your window). So, make of that what you want.

Comment: But I just need 4 of them: the "author", "body", "created_utc" and "score". The problem is that I don't know how to somehow unfold that list of lists, it seems to be a mess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need a single dataset,

```
library(purrr)
out <- map_dfr(p,  
   ~ .x[c('author', 'body', 'created_utc', 'score')] %>% stack, .id = 'grp')
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
out <- type.convert(as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, 
  lapply(p, function(x) do.call(c, x[c('author', 'body', 
        'created_utc', 'score')])))), as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @akrun!!